# what simple way to collect data and arrange in horizontal scrolling view in flutter

Tags: flutter

this is the service code below:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

class CarServices {
  Future<List> getCars() async {
    String url = "https://rider.spatrum.com/api/select_rides";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    Map values = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return values["data"];
    //print(values["data"]);
  }
}
```

the above returns json value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ListView.builder` with `Axis.horizontal`

```
return Container(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Card(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  Payload({
    this.data,
    this.message,
  });

  List<Car> data;
  String message;

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        data: List<Car>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Car.fromJson(x))),
        message: json["message"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "message": message,
      };
}

class Car {
  Car({
    this.id,
    this.vehicletype,
    this.displayname,
    this.icon,
    this.baseFare,
    this.baseKm,
    this.isenable,
    this.seats,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.deletedAt,
  });

  int id;
  String vehicletype;
  String displayname;
  dynamic icon;
  String baseFare;
  String baseKm;
  String isenable;
  String seats;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;
  dynamic deletedAt;

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Car(
        id: json["id"],
        vehicletype: json["vehicletype"],
        displayname: json["displayname"],
        icon: json["icon"],
        baseFare: json["base_fare"],
        baseKm: json["base_km"],
        isenable: json["isenable"],
        seats: json["seats"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "vehicletype": vehicletype,
        "displayname": displayname,
        "icon": icon,
        "base_fare": baseFare,
        "base_km": baseKm,
        "isenable": isenable,
        "seats": seats,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "deleted_at": deletedAt,
      };
}

class CarServices {
  Future<List<Car>> getCars() async {
    String url = "https://rider.spatrum.com/api/select_rides";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    Map values = jsonDecode(response.body);
    //return values["data"];
    return List<Car>.from(values["data"].map((x) => Car.fromJson(x)));
    //print(values["data"]);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<Car>> _future;
  CarServices _carServices = CarServices();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _carServices.getCars();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Car>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                      height: 100,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              width: 100,
                              child: Card(
                                  elevation: 6.0,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 6.0,
                                        bottom: 6.0,
                                        left: 8.0,
                                        right: 8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(snapshot.data[index].vehicletype
                                            .toString()),
                                        Text(
                                          "seats ${snapshot.data[index].seats}",
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            );
                          }),
                    );
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a listview.Builder inside a Future Builder. Since you are performing an async operation, future builder is needed to get data correctly.

https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9